# How can I show server response one time and clear after first event in knockout.js?

Tags: knockout.js

After ajax post I want to show "Your order received : link". After users first interaction(any changes in viewModel) I want to clear message.

How can I do that with knockout.js

View:

```
<div data-bind="text:serverResponse,visible:serverResponseActive"></div>
```

Maybe writable computed observables? How?

Comment: Are we talking a lot of properties on the view model? You can subscribe to changes, but that's a bit of a killer if you have to do it on a lot of properties.

Comment: Yes exactly there are alot of properties.  I thought that I could handle all changes with one computed observable, but I could not make it.

Comment: Might be good a use for the "simple" dirty flag from this post: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html

Comment: Niemeyer could you add this link as response. I will accept it:) It works!

Answer (score 1):

One approach you could try is adding a `event` binding to any client-interactable element you want to clear the server message from. So, something like:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="event: { mouseover: clearResposne, click: clearResponse}" />

// viewmodel code (object literal style)
clearResponse: function() { this.serverResponseActive = false; },
```

Could get a little messy for a large page, but for one or two things, it would be pretty neat and compact.

Another approach would be to just set a timeout when the server response is received that clears the flag in x seconds.

```
// In the view model (constructed object style)
var self = this; // to un-confuse the closure function 'this'

// In the ajax response
setTimeout(function() { self.serverResponseActive = false }, 5000);
```

Combine the two for a delay after a user action.

Edit: A third approach, inspired bey your

> After users first interaction(any changes in viewModel) I want to clear message.

Manually subscribe to every other observable in your viewModel. could be very messy if you have a bunch of observables.

```
myViewModel.personName.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    setTimeout(function() { self.serverResponseActive = false }, 5000);
});
```

If you really have a whole bunch of observables, consider making custom bindings for them that have the subscription/timeout baked in.

Comment: My way is third approach and I can implement niemeyer's solution : knockmeout.net/2011/05/… . Bu thanks for your response